# Meteor userId is present but user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

While rendering my react component I'm getting `Meteor.user()` `null`.  Then I tried accessing `Meteor.userId()` and got it correct as the logged in user's id. Also tried to access the user by `Meteor.users.findOne()` but didn't succeed.

**My question is, why user object is being undefined though the userid is  accessible?**

I used following code snippet to test:

```
var uid = Meteor.userId();
console.log(uid);                                 // printed the _id correctly

var usr = Meteor.user();                
console.log(usr);                                 // undefined 

var usr1 = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: uid});
console.log(usr1);                                // undefined
```

Comment: Are you running the code on server, client or both?

Comment: running in client  only

Comment: And do you have the corresponding publication from the server to retrieve the user's data?

Comment: no, didn't subscribed to any particular publication. and I also removed the autopublish paackage. do I need to subscribe to get the logged it user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Meteor.userId()` is available immediately on login. `Meteor.user()` requires the object be delivered via DDP to the client so it's not immediately available.

By default the `profile` key is published. Since you've turned off autopublish you may want to publish your own specific set of keys from the user.

I usually have:

server:

```
Meteor.publish('me',function(){
  if ( this.userId ) return Meteor.users.find(this.userId,{ fields: { key1: 1, key2: 1 ...}});
  this.ready();
});
```

client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('me');
```

You can also publish information about other users but there the list of keys to be shared is typically much smaller. For example you usually don't want to share the email addresses of other users with the logged-in user.

Answer (score 2):

Meteor.user() is indeed not directly available, you can try the following:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  var uid = Meteor.userId();
  console.log(uid);                                 // printed the _id       correctly

  var usr = Meteor.user();                
  console.log(usr);                                 // undefined 

  var usr1 = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: uid});
  console.log(usr1);  
});
```

This should first print undefined and after that print the correct user.